# Limits in complex analysis of 'basic' functions

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Find
$$L=\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} e^{z}.$$

First I simply wrote down the answer $1$ but I realise that I can't just mimic things I'd do in the complex case that I would have done for the real case. I then let $z = x+iy$ where $x,y$ are real so the limit is
$$L = \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} e^x e^{iy}\\ = \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow 0} |e^x e^{iy}| = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} e^x$$
which does in fact equal $1$ (just a simple limit in the real case).
I was wondering - did I really have to go through these steps (transforming it into a multivariable limit)? How would I justify the limit?

Comment: As $\exp(z)$ is holomorphic it is also continuous, hence the limit is simply $\exp(0)$. But the solution you gave is more basic, which is probably what you are asked to do in the exercise.

Comment: In both arguments, at the very last step you did exactly the same: invoking the continuity of $e^z$ at $z=0$. If you added $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}e^{x}=\lim_{x\to0}e^x$ then it would be clear that you are using the continuity of $e^x$ at $x=0$ as a real function.

Comment: @Hellen: But in the last line he only had a univariate limit, which means he used $\exp(x)$ is continuous. Is it really necessary to show that $\exp(x)$ is continuous in $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @MrYouMath No. He still has a function of complex variable $z\mapsto e^{Re(z)}$

Comment: @MrYouMath The domain. Just sit on it for a while until you get it.

Comment: @Hellen: I think the only problem in the derivation is the step from the first limit to the second with the magnitudes. The last step/conclusion is correct. But nevermind, I will not argue on that.

Comment: @MrYouMath I haven't said the last step is incorrect I am only saying that unless one really is going to make (explicit) a reduction from having to invoke the continuity of $e^z$ as a function of complex variable to having to invoke the continuity of $e^x$ as a function of real variable, then all the work is unnecessary. As written, at the end, he is having to use the continuity of the complex variable function, which he could have just use directly without putting absolute value. So, nothing was gained.

Comment: So usually complex variable limits invoke continuity as opposed to changing it to multivariable limits?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours well, we usually do the same in multivariable limits too. Wether are you in the complex or in the real world, we first check continuity - if our function is continuous, nothing needs to be done and the limit is simply evaluating the function. The problem is where continuity fails - and that's where calculating limits gets interesting, and all your techniques kicks in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots,$$you know that$$0\leqslant|e^z-1|=\left|z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots\right|\leqslant|z|+\frac{|z|^2}{2!}+\frac{|z|^3}{3!}+\cdots=e^{|z|}-1.$$Since $\lim_{z\to0}e^{|z|}-1=0$, it follows that $\lim_{z\to0}|e^z-1|=0$, which is the same thing as stating that $\lim_{z\to0}e^z-1=0$.